# Need help replacing single quotes in bash script

Tags: bash, quotes, replace

i am trying to replace the quotes in a string in my bash script. i have a variable that will be placed in a mysql query that may possibly have a single quote in it. i want to replace any `'` with `\'` so i can escape any quote and not screw up my query.

i tried this as a test but it doesn't work:

```
text="bobby's test"
echo ${text/#'/\\\'}
```

what am i doing wrong or is there even a better way to do this that i havent thought of? i prefer to not have to use sed or anything as well.

Comment: What is your use case? Are you *sure* you need to escape the quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sh
echo "${text//\'/\'}"
```

Make sure you use the double quotes on the outside, or you are going to need more escaping (ugh).