# Bash parameter expansion ${parameter/pattern/string} with quotes

Tags: bash, replace, quotes

It's my first post on SO (long time lurker though) so I apologies in advance for the numerous "faux pas" and other mistakes I am certainly about to make.

I've been looking on google for a while now trying to find an answer to how quotes are parsed when inside parameter expansion that are inside double quotes and it seems that I either have the wrong keywords or a very twisted mind for attempting this.

For example, if I have a string like `It's a complicated string`, I would like to transform that string into the sequence `It'\''s a complicated string` using bash's parameter expansion `${parameter/pattern/string}`. **I know I can achieve that result using one of many other builtin or external tool (I'm quite fond of sed myself), but this question really is about understanding what is going on in bash's mind so that I can put my own mind to ease.**

[Bash's reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) don't seem to specify what happen in that special case when describing its "pattern" and [the closest question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291150/need-help-replacing-single-quotes-in-bash-script) doesn't seem to work in my case :

```
$ echo "$str"
It's a complicated string
$ echo "${str//'/'\''}"
> ^C
$ echo "${str//'/'\''}"
> ^C
$ echo "${str//\'/'\''}"
> ^C
$ echo "${str//\'/\'\''}"
> ^C
$ echo "${str//\'/\'\'\'}"
It\'\'\'s a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\\'/\'\'\'}"
It's a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\\'/\\'\'\'}"
It's a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\\'/\\'\\'\'}"
It's a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\\'/\\'\\'\\'}"
It's a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\\\'/\\'\\'\\'}"
> ^C
$ echo "${str//\\\'/\\\'\\'\\'}"
It's a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\\\'/\\\'\\\'\\'}"
> ^C
$ echo "${str//\\\'/\\\'\\\'\\\'}"
It's a complicated string
```

(The `> ^C` lines means that the quotes were not parsed correctly and I was prompted for more input, which I ruthlessly deny each time using Ctrl-C.)

Would any of you be kind enough to explain how exactly bash sees this? I really hope it's just a communication problem between us, I kinda like him. :)

**EDIT:**

For those wondering, Etan Reisner's answer works :

```
$ q=\'
$ echo "${str//\'/$q\'$q}"
It'\''s a complicated string
```

As for sputnick's answer, I'm even more puzzled :

```
$ echo "${str//\047/\047\\\047\047}"
It's a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\047/\047\047}"
It's a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\'/\047\'\047}"
It\047\'\047s a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\'/\047\047\047}"
It\047\047\047s a complicated string
$ echo "${str//'/\047\047\047}"
> ^C
$ echo "${str//\047/\047\047\047}"
It's a complicated string
$ echo "${str//\047/\047\\\047\047}"
It's a complicated string
```

**EDIT2 :**

Apparently this is a bug affecting at least bash 4.1 and 4.2 and fixed in bash 4.3. Therefore, there is nothing to understand from the above test.

Comment: With `\\'`, for bash, you're having a backslash and you're opening a single quote (and Bash is waiting for you to close it—and you cancel that by presing Ctrl-C). Try something fun: instead of pressing Ctrl-C, type `I love bananas'}"` and enjoy.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I could understand that behavior in the "pattern" section of `${parameter/pattern/string}`, but in the "string" section, surely all characters should be litterals?

Comment: A better question is, why do you want to create such a string? The original is a perfectly valid string containing a single quote; your edit seems to be attempting to add a quoted single quote (incorrectly, I might add) to the string in an attempt to include `bash` syntax in the string.

Comment: @chepner Not if you put my new string between single quotes : `'It'\''s a complicated string'` which would be a way to ensure that whatever is in that string doesn't get evaluated.

Comment: The only thing I found in the manual: _In each of the cases below, word is subject to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion._ The documentation is maybe not clear enough (as it should also specify string). To answer your question: no, characters in string _are not_ literal!

Comment: `\047` in the *pattern* isn't being seen as `'` it seems to be seen as literal characters. Backslash, `0`, `4`, and `7`. See `declare -- s="foo\\047bar"; echo "${s//\047/X}"` -> `foo\Xbar`.

Comment: @user43791 What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish with your modified string?

Comment: @EtanReisner From the manual: _The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion._ so no surprises here.

Comment: @chepner He seems to be trying to use this to make a string shell safe. Wrap in single quotes and "escape" every internal single quote.

Comment: @chepner Initially, I was trying to safely pass an argument across layers of an ssh chain command I was constructing on the fly (ssh host1 ssh host2 ssh host3 cmd arg1 arg2 arg3 ...). As I said, there are many other ways of doing this. For that reason, the question is about bash's behavior, not how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works (with or without double quotes):

```
echo "${str//\'/\'\\\'\'}"
```

Each single quote is escaped with a backslash to prevent it from beginning a single-quoted string. The literal backslash is also escaped in the replacement pattern.

---

Direct copy-and-paste from a `bash` 4.3 session:

```
$ str="It's a complicated string"
$ echo "${str//\'/\'\\\'\'}"
It'\''s a complicated string
$ echo ${str//\'/\'\\\'\'}
It'\''s a complicated string
```

The output in `bash` 3.2 is identical.

Comment: With quotes that doesn't generate the desired output. Without quotes it does though but that's likely not safe anymore.

Comment: Etan's right : I get `It\'\\'\'s a complicated string` when I run this

Comment: Really? I'm getting what I thought was the desired output in both 3.2 and 4.3.

Comment: @chepner Strange... I'm on bash 4.2 and I get the wrong output with and without posix mode. I'll try on a more recent bash version when I get home. Maybe I just discovered a "feature" affecting only 4.2?

Comment: 4.1 shows the same output you show above. This might be a bug introduced in 4.0 (or 4.1?) that was fixed in 4.3.

Comment: @chepner A quick google search for "bash brace expansion bug" seems to yield results that points to a bug (mailing list exchanges and [the changes between bash versions](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) ), so I'll accept your answer as the right one. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying weird escaping game, try to use `ascii` representation of the single quote : `\047`

See

```
man 7 ascii
```

Comment: My bash doesn't seem to see any difference between a litteral `\` and the escape sequence `\047` (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain what bash is doing exactly but similarly to @sputnick my suggestion is to just not play the game.

```
q=\'
echo "${str//\'/$q\'$q}"
```

Comment: This does work (I edited my question to reflect that), but I still don't understand the strange behavior of bash while parsing my initial command line.